# VS 2013 Xact Audio Engine-File not found exception

Tags: c#, audio, monogame, content-pipeline

I am attempting to create Windows monogame application in which I have to play multiple sounds simultaneously. When I found one solution was using [XACT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203895(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx). However when it came to audio engine's creation of instance, it throws `File not found exception`.

At this code line :

```
        audioEngine = new AudioEngine("Content/Audio/GameAudio.xgs");
```

How to go about rectifying this error?

Comment: Silly questions time: Does Content/Audio/GameAudio.xgs exist? What's its full path?

Comment: But the tutorials i followed had this same path.. They had the Audio folder inside Content folder itself and they used this path.  Ok ill try with the full path :)

Comment: @StephenKennedy :  Now i gave like this    :                audioEngine = new AudioEngine("C:/Users/computer/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/proj1/proj1/proj1.Windows/Content/Audio/GameAudio.xgs");
  Now i got this : An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @jincyabraham regarding the above comment, you need to understand something regarding providing path in a code. A path should be relative to the source code, you seriously expected it to work?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT : relative to source code means? from the current working directory kind? It was that way that i tried first. Please look at the code given above if thats the case. And this is exactly the same way the tutorial was like- in providing the path.